# How to duplicate render layer

Tags: render-layers

could be render layer duplicated? With all its properties and freestyle settings preserved ?

There is only button for adding, but newly added layer is not set.

[image: render layers sshot]

Comment: How about getting into the layer. selecting all objects with box select, (not sure if A is safe) and copy pasting it to a new scene or a vacant layer? (CTL-C / CTL-V)

Comment: There's an addon for [copying / pasting render layers](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Copy_Render_Layer) , It was told to have some [troubles](https://developer.blender.org/T34109) although if copying inside of the same file it should work with recent Blender versions..

Comment: It's better to use another approach to copy freestyle setitngs from one layer to another, see related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/how-to-move-freestyle-line-sets-to-another-layer

Comment: thanks @Mr Zak - i have try this plugin, it looks promising. It cloned layer, but did not keep freestyle settings...

Comment: yeah, the addon doesn't do that, hence the related link.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of your Blender window, select *Cycles Render.*
In the *Screen-layout* drop-down, select *Compositing.*
At the bottom of that panel, put a check next to *Use Nodes.*

You can now branch the *Render Layers Image* output to several nodes.
You get to decide which nodes to use.  Just Add whichever ones you need,
then send the output from your nodes to *Composite Image.*

[image: NodeSplit]

Comment: Thanks @Doyousketch2, this can help sometimes, but real copy of render-layer creates new item usefull as start point for changing settings and turning into completly different one.